# How can I memory-efficiently iterate over a huge range of numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, performance, recursion

The following bash script runs out of memory when I run it on much larger ranges, e.g., PLU up to 1.2M and DEPENDENCE up to 50. How can I execute the same logic (recursively or otherwise) without requiring all that memory?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for PLU in {1..10}
do      
    for DEPENDENCE in {1..5}
    do
        echo $PLU $DEPENDENCE
    done
done
```

I tried changing the for sitax with `for ((i=0; i<10; i++))` but stills run out of memory in sometime

Comment: If the `{1..10}` syntax makes your computer run out of memory when the upper limit is high, it is because it generates the whole list of numbers and then passes it to a loop.

Comment: I don't recommend recursion: a simple pair of nested loops that don't save the list of indices in memory will do.

Comment: The `for ((i=0; i<10; i++))` approach definitely shouldn't run out of memory -- there has to be something else going on if it does. Can you show everything involved in producing the OOM error? If you're doing something like `var=$(yourscript)`, f/e, that means all of `yourscript`'s output goes to memory, so _that's_ where you could hit the issue.

Comment: Do note that part of the [mre] definition is making sure that the code given _actually reproduces the problem_. If just changing `10` to `12000000` and copying-and-pasting isn't enough to reproduce the bug, then the question needs to be edited until a mere copy-and-paste _does_ cause the out-of-memory error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using different tools for this? If performance is a concern generating the output from awk took `real   0m0.245s` . Using Charles's bash version took `real 0m57.367s`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(a=1;a<=120000;a++){for(b=1;b<=10;b++){print a,b}}}' > large.lst
```

For formatted output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(a=1;a<=120000;a++){for(b=1;b<=10;b++){printf "this is a value: %s, this is b value: %s\n",a,b}}}' > large.lst
```

EDIT 2:
And to prove Charle's point below about "not necessary to have a one liner" - one could put the code in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  for (a = 1; a <= 12000; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
      printf "this is a value: %s, this is b value: %s\n", a, b
    }
  }
}
```

...either run as an executable itself, or (if saved as `plu_list.awk`) with:

```
awk -f plu_list.awk
```

Comment: Could you explain what awk exactly does and why is a better alternative?

Comment: @AndersonJimenez, ...for one, awk is a lot faster (once it's running; startup takes longer than using bash builtins, but printing this may numbers, the faster I/O of awk will make more sense). For another, it supports exponential notation, so while you can't put in `1.2m` exactly, you can put `1.2e7`

Comment: And how can I use this but printing a formatted string ... I mean do something like this: 
'awk 'BEGIN{for(a=1;a<=120000;a++){for(b=1;b<=10;b++){print this is a value: a, this is b value:b}}}' > large.lst '  **(I'm sorry I don't know how to writte code in comments )**

Comment: @AndersonJimenez, awk supports `printf`. Its manual is worth reading. BTW, there's no reason an awk script has to be a one-liner -- you can use line breaks / indentation / etc to make it more readable.

Comment: @AndersonJimenez - did Charles's comments and my edit help?

Comment: @tink yeah, thank you very much. Your solution helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A [C-style for loop](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) will avoid needing to realize all the numbers into memory before the loop starts, and so will continue to work with any numbers that bash's integer representation is able to handle:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((plu=1; plu<=10; plu++)); do
    for ((dependence=1; dependence<=5; dependence++)); do
        echo "$plu $dependence"
    done
done
```

BTW, note that all-caps names are used for variables built into or with special meaning to the shell. Application-defined variables should have names with at least one lower-case character. See the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) describing this convention; read it keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace, so the same conventions necessarily apply to both.

Comment: is bash's integer representation able to handle: 1.2M?

Comment: Do you mean the exact string `1.2M`, on the value to which it refers? `echo "$(( 1000 * 1000 * 12 / 10 ))"` comes out fine (on a 64-bit system, haven't looked at behavior on a 32-bit host), so there you are.

Comment: @AndersonJimenez, ...and even if it you were on a system where the maximum integer size was too small, it wouldn't be an out-of-memory error; instead, it would overflow and wrap around to a smaller number, and stop at that other number instead.